# Adding Optional.isPresent() inside Java 8 Comparator

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Below is my Java 8 code, when I run Sonar, I am getting "**Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value.**" message.  Please help me how to add `isPresent()` for `subPlan.getTaxWthholding().getFederalTaxDetails().getFederalTaxPercentage().`

```
SubPlan maxSubPlan = subPlanList.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.getIsSelected())
    .max(Comparator.comparing(subPlan ->
         subPlan.getTaxWthholding().getFederalTaxDetails().getFederalTaxPercentage()))
    .get();
```

Comment: Law of Demeter anyone? If that's the only Sonar warning you get I suppose you must have turned the rest of them off...

Comment: see @Eran answer, using get alone is unsafe, it throws exception if not present, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it wants you to add `isPresent` inside the `Comparator`.

The problem is probably the last `get()`.

`max()` may return an empty `Optional` (if `subPlanList` is empty, or if the `filter` step filtered out all the elements), so you should replace `get()` with either `orElse(defaultValue)`, `orElseGet()` or `orElseThrow()`.